# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{x^2+x+1} \text{d}x$ using complex methods

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

For $\alpha \in (-1,1)\setminus\{0\}$ I have the following integral, that needs to be evaluated using complex methods (rather than real methods).$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{x^2+x+1} \text{d}x$$

Since this is an integral from $0$ to $\infty$ rather than $-\infty$ to $\infty$, we can't just use a direct application of Jordan's lemma even if we only had $1/(x^2+x+1)$ (the $x^\alpha$ would probably also complicate things).

Virtually every other example I've seen has a simpler denominator that's either even (allowing use of the $-\infty$ to $\infty$ case) or of a simple form like $x^n+1$ where the residue theorem around a sector with angle $2 \pi i/n$ can be used. However we can't directly use a method like that in this case.

We can see that $x^2+x+1=(x-e^{2\pi i/3})(x-e^{4\pi i/3}$) which gives where the poles of the function are for $\alpha>0$ but again I have no idea how to find a suitable contour. How would you go about doing this integral using complex methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use the contour $\gamma_r$ which is the circle $|z|=r$ and the top and bottom of the interval $[0,r]$.

Comment: What does the top and bottom of the interval mean?

Comment: @Integral12 This is a standard "keyhole" contour; see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_4_%E2%80%93_branch_cuts

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245405/how-to-solve-the-integral-through-a-contour-with-branch-points

Comment: @Integral12 If you try this approach, just be careful with phase: the poles are $e^{2\pi i/3},\,e^{4\pi i/3}$, **not** $e^{\pm2\pi i/3}$. You should get$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\alpha\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+x+1}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\frac{\sin\frac{\alpha\pi}{3}}{\sin(\alpha\pi)}.$$Feel free to use $\alpha\to0^+$ for a sanity check.